# Generate auto-increment int column in MariaDB with EFCore

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, mariadb, auto-increment

**The Problem:**

I'm trying to create a table with efcore in .netcore 2.2 using codefirst having an auto-increment integer primary key starting at 0. All solutions i found result in either an error on adding migration or the auto-incrementing works but start at int.MinValue.

All the following solutions have been tried seperated, not combined:

**Solution 1:**

Do nothing. Just let efcore do its default thing.

-> The column auto-increments but starts at int.MinValue

**Solution 2:**

setting annotation `"[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]"` on primary key.

-> The column auto-increments but starts at int.MinValue




**Solution 3:**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .Property(u => u.Id)
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

-> The column auto-increments but starts at int.MinValue

**Solution 4:**

```
modelBuilder.HasSequence<int>("User_seq")
    .StartsAt(0)
    .IncrementsBy(1);

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .Property(u => u.Id)
    .HasDefaultValueSql("NEXT VALUE FOR User_seq");
```

-> Adding a migration fails with an error:

```
    "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SEQUENCE User_seq START WITH 0 INCREMENT BY 1' at line 1"
```

**Solution 5:**

changing the datatype of Id to uint.

-> The column auto-increments but starts at int.MaxValue

**My User entity:**

```
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName{ get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

**Provider used:** Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql

**To clarify my question:** How do I create an auto-incrementing integer primary key column starting at 0 incrementing by 1 in MariaDB using efcore codefirst?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.

MariaDB (MySQL) treats 0 as meaning to create a new `AUTO_INCREMENT` value.

Do not assume properties of `AUTO_INCREMENT` that it does not provide.  It only says that each new value will be different than the existing values.

Probably `int.MinValue` is some big negative value (-2^31).